# place text on top and button of a Button css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new in HTML CSS, I have a button with the following specification:

```
.Btns {
            width:200px;              
            height:75px;
            background-color:lightblue;
            color:black;
            font-weight:bold;

        }
```

here is my Button:

```
<button id="btnProduct" type="button" class="Btns"/>
```

an here i give it value using jquery:

```
 $("#btnProduct").html('Production:'+sumOfpro+' Kw/h');
```

sumOfpro is an integer value I get it from Ajax, anyway, my question is how can I put the text on top of the button and the value in the middle or bottom?
by text, I mean production and value I mean sumOfpro, thanks for your help

Comment: Buttons can contain HTML.  Nest two elements inside the button, one for the string "Production", one for the sumOfPro+" Kw/h", and position them within the button exactly the same way you would position any other HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/48mah2jx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.Btns {
            width:200px;              
            height:75px;
            background-color:lightblue;
            color:black;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<button id="btnProduct" type="button" class="Btns">Production: 123<br/><br/><br/>Kw/h</button>
```

Comment: is it possible to put the Production text upper?i mean close to the border line

Comment: you can increase height between both lines by adding more `<br/>`. take a look on updated fiddle